# Simulate press hard key in protractor

Tags: protractor, mobile-automation

I am using Protractor for testing my web application. During the use of the app, I want to press a hard key on the device, like the home screen, then the app will be minimized and I will see the device's home screen. After that, I want to tap again on the app, and I want to see the screen I was before tapping on the home screen key.

- By any chance, Protractor is able to simulate this action? If not, which tool do you recommend I can integrate with Protractor?
- Do you think it is a good approach to automate just this touch scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor supports all webdriverjs keys

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Key.html

HOME is one of them , you can use these in protractor using hte "protractor" global function

```
protractor.key.HOME
```

and could be used with sendKeys

```
 element.sendKeys(protractor.key.HOME)

 browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.HOME).perform();
```

Comment: Hi @PDHide, I think I was not clear. What I want is not to press the Home key of the laptop for instance, but instead I want to press the home key, recent apps key or return key of the **mobile device**.